# Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex

Tags: apache, http, ssl

I'm sure this question has been asked and answered, but I'm not finding a solution. I have a virtual host I have just added SSL to, and it isns't working as expected. The non-SSL version is working properly. Below is what I've got in httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost mysite.com:443>
  ServerAdmin email@myemail.com
  ServerName  mysite.com
  ServerAlias www.mysite.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/www.mysite.com

  <Directory /var/www/html/www.mysite.com>
      DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      allow from all
              Require all granted
  </Directory>

  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/my.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/my.key
</VirtualHost>
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
[Thu Jan 11 12:29:58.984354 2018] [autoindex:error] [pid 19998] [client 
IP:38470] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching 
DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory 
index forbidden by Options directive
```

Obviously, I've got the directory set as /var/www/html/www.mysite.com, but it's trying to serve content directly from /var/www/html.

I'm sure this is something simple, but my brain is already oatmeal from working on this site all day, so I'm probably just failing to see what's right in front of my face.

Thanks!

Comment: obviously the error message is produced by another Virtual Host.

Comment: No, I explained the error below.

Answer (score 5):

Fixed it. Simple enough, as I assumed. Change:

```
<VirtualHost mysite.com:443>
```

To:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
```

Comment: hey @james I'm facing the same issue. but once i use this option, i get a 502 error instead.